# Integrating express.js to an Existing vue.js/webpack Project

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

I understand that it is possible to integrate vue.js and webpack to an existing express.js project. Is the reverse possible, adding express.js to an existing vue.js/webpack project which currently uses only node.js without a framework? In the affirmative, if the vue.js project was created at the root folder level of the project, can I create a sub-folder at the root level to include the express.js files? Considering that the vue.js client project will not be found in a separate sub-folder (but at the root of the main project), will this create conflicts with the express.js deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express.js is a server framework using node.js. Vue.js is a frontend UI framework. So yes, you can use both on same server.

> ...adding express.js to an existing vue.js/webpack project which currently uses only node.js without a framework? In the affirmative, if the vue.js project was created at the root folder level of the project, can I create a sub-folder at the root level to include the express.js files?

Yes you can do like that. In fact, no matter where you create your express.js server, it will launched at domain:port you define (usually localhost:3000).

> Considering that the vue.js client project will not be found in a separate sub-folder (but at the root of the main project), will this create conflicts with the express.js deployment?

You will have to build your vue.js frontend in a `dist` folder, and tell express.js to use this folder...

Comment: Thank you for your answer ManUtopiK.